# Mounting container volume from the hosts' drive?

Tags: mysql, docker

im setting up a mysql container like so:

docker run -v /srv/information-db:/var/lib/mysql tutum/mysql /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db"

now, this works when nothing is mounted on /srv on the host, but when i mount my drive, docker seems to write to the underlying filesystem (/), eg:

```
/]# ls -l /srv
total 0
/]# mount /dev/xvdc1 /srv
/]# mount
...
/dev/xvdc1 on /srv type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)

/]# docker run -v /srv/information-db:/var/lib/mysql tutum/mysql /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db"

/]# ls -l /srv
total 16
drwx------. 2 root root 16384 Apr 22 18:05 lost+found
/]# umount /dev/xvdc1
/]# ls -l /srv
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 4 102 root 4096 Apr 22 18:24 information-db
```

Anyone seen this behaviour / have a solution?
Cheers

Comment: I was fortunately able to solve in this particular case by nuking the whole setup from orbit (removing docker entirely, upgrading the kernel and installing the latest and greatest).
Still keen to know if anyone else has thoughts on this

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something like that. Try to perform `stat -c %i` checks both inside the host and container before and after mount event (in order to get inode values of the target dirs). I guess they're mismatched for a some reason when you mount external device.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer :)
I got the following results, but im not sure how to interpret them:
Before mount:

container: (/var/lib/mysql) 2228226 
host:         (/srv/information-db) 2228226 

After mount:

container: (/var/lib/mysql) 2228226
host: (/srv/information-db not present ) []

note the dir is not present on the host after mounting, only by unmounting afterwards does it present itself ( as in the original question ) and that returns the same result ( 2228226 )